# Many rg commands started by vscode that consume 99% of CPUs

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, ripgrep

I'm working inside a very big github repo, say its structure is like

```
project-root
├── project-1
│   ├── subproject-a
│   └── subproject-others
└── project-2
    ├── subproject-b
    └── subproject-others
```

There are many projects, each contains many subprojects. I'm just working on one of the subprojects (e.g. `subproject-a`). When I opened vscode inside the subproject (it's a python subproject), I noticed that it launches many `rg` commands like below, and my CPU usage goes above 99%. I wonder what these rg commands are about? Are they just searching for stuffs inside the subproject, or the whole git repo, which contains tens of thousands of files? Why do they consume so many resources? How could I avoid that, please?

> `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/vscode-ripgrep/bin/rg --files --hidden --case-sensitive -g **/*.go/** -g **/*.go -g !**/.git -g !**/.svn -g !**/.hg -g !**/CVS -g !**/.DS_Store -g !**/.classpath -g !**/.factorypath -g !**/.project -g !**/.settings -g !**/node_modules -g !**/bower_components -g !**/*.code-search --no-ignore-parent --follow --quiet --no-config --no-ignore-global`

Comment: where do you see these commands logged?

Comment: @rioV8, in htop

Comment: it is a [program written in rust](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) that is an enhanced replacement for `grep`. Looking at your `rg` command it isn't searching for anything. is it only looking in `.go` files. Maybe ask via an VSC issue why they need to call it so often (on a MacOS) and what they are searching for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that there are four symlink folders with over 700k files in them. These folders are usually ignored in `/project-root/.gitginore`. So `rg` by default would ignore searching in them.

But here because of `--no-ignore-parent --follow` flags, they are being searched nonetheless.

I added these folders to `/project-root/project-1/subproject-a/.gitignore` again, and now these `rg` commands don't take so much cpu resource anymore.

Comment: then what is the reason to use `--no-ignore-parent` argument. the crux of `.gitignore` is that you locally specify what extra stuff you want to be ignored.

Comment: I don't know why `--no-ignore-parent` is used. I also find an alternative way is to exclude folders in vscode settings, which also seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving my solution in case works for anyone else, none of the other solutions worked for me and I discovered that this only happened when I tried to `ng build` the project.

I read somewhere (can't remember where exactly) that the extension Auto Import trigger this rg process. I tried disabling it and my Mac just came back to normal. If you have the extension, try this, it may work.